# Count number of people across multiple columns with criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I have a worksheet that has 6 columns for each employee and family members birthdays.  I am looking to get the total number of kids that are 20 years old and younger without adding any additional columns based on the date in cell B1.  I looked into using COUNTIF, but it needs a range to execute.

Here is how my workbook looks:
[image]

I am looking for one formula that takes all birthdays from columns C-F and counts how many children are younger than 20 years old.  Is this possible?

Answers I am seeking from formula:
[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIF():

```
=COUNTIF(C3:F3,">" & DATE(YEAR($B$1)-20,MONTH($B$1),DAY($B$1)))
```

[image]

Comment: this works perfectly!  How would I change the formula if I wanted to do ages >= 21 but <= 24?

Comment: Change to COUNTIFS and use the same range with the new operands and the requisite date().

Comment: Are you able to supply how the formula would look?  I am marking your post as the answer.

Comment: new question get new posts, they are free to post.  I am away from my computer and it is hard to do formulas on the phone. Link to this question when you ask the new one and show how you tried to modify.

Comment: I have created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49287644/count-number-of-people-across-multiple-columns-with-criteria-2

Comment: Why not use something like `=COUNTIF(C3:F3,">"&$B$1-20*365)`?  This would be a bit cleaner than needing to refer to `$B$1` three times.

Comment: @lebelinoz because of Leap Year, you would be off at least 4 to 5 days.

Comment: @ScottCraner Just multiply by 365.25 instead of 365.  Or forget about offsets in the formula and put the correct date of 20 years ago in cell B1.  You get the idea...

Comment: @lebelinoz but again depending on when the year was even 365.25 would get you off.  But it all depends on the what the OP wants for accuracy.  They are good ideas, and it depends, I answered with the most accurate, in my mind, with the data given by the OP.  As the OP's follow up would suggest the window of count may be based on one date but bracketed by 2 numbers.  So where I appreciate the opinion and suggestion, given the data in this question, I feel this is the most accurate method.

Comment: I changed the date to 01/01/2017 and running into issues with the under 20 years old formula. A child born 10/31/1996 and 01/01/1998 would be 20 and 19 respectively. The formula is saying any date greater than = 01/01/1997 would count, but is only counting one child instead of two though both are under 20. Thoughts?

Comment: `10/31/1996` is less than `01/01/1997`  If you want any one that is 20 or younger on that date you will need to change the criteria to `DATE(YEAR($B$1)-21,MONTH($B$1),DAY($B$1)+1)` this will get anyone that is 20 even if it is 1 day before their 21st birthday. @Hery0502

Comment: @ScottCraner - does the formula from the other post have to be updated as well with similar logic?

Comment: Yes, you will. @Hery0502