# Count number of people across multiple columns with criteria 2

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

Here is the original question:

[Count number of people across multiple columns with criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49285970/count-number-of-people-across-multiple-columns-with-criteria/49286078?noredirect=1#comment85576572_49286078)

Original formula:

```
=COUNTIF(C3:F3,">" & DATE(YEAR($B$1)-20,MONTH($B$1),DAY($B$1)))
```

I am looking to modify the formula to count ages >= 21 and <= 24.

Here is what I have tried:

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(C3:F3),"<="&DATE(YEAR($E$4)-21,MONTH($E$4),DAY($E$4)&">="&DATE(YEAR($E$4)-24,MONTH($E$4),DAY($E$4))))
```

Any help is must appreciated!

Comment: As @ScottCraner stated, please show us how you attempted to modify the formula to fit your needs. You're going to want to use a `COUNTIFS`, which looks like this: `COUNTIFS(criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2], [criteria2])`, with those values in **[** & **]** being optional (though needed, in your case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your COUNTIFS is wrong.  You need to put the range twice not use `&` to add criteria:

```
=COUNTIFS(C3:F3,"<="&DATE(YEAR($E$4)-21,MONTH($E$4),DAY($E$4)),C3:F3,">="&DATE(YEAR($E$4)-24,MONTH($E$4),DAY($E$4))))
```

Comment: This formula counts everyone between 20 and 24, that is only 1 that fits that.